# Initializing state with localstorage Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have an application that has a cart in Next.js, the cart is a piece of state that is also is assigned to a useContext to make it accessible to all props. In Next, it lives in the "App" component. I initialize the state with an empty array for now.

```
_app.js:

const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
```

The issue comes by implementing localStorage, which is client side so Next can't recognize it. Makes sense to me. The issue comes when I want to initialize state with the localStorage of cart. I have it all implemented properly to where the cart syncs with localStorage (using useEffect)

```
useEffect(()=>{
   localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems))
},[cartItems])
```

I then tried to use a useEffect hook to set the state to the localStorage object, but here is the issue.

localStorage "cart" key is set to the value of cart -> when I reload the page, it then sees the cart is empty (because the state is initialized before the useEffect is run) which then sets localStorage to be an empty cart, which then sets the state to an empty array

How can I initialize state with localStorage in Next? Can I put the cart state in another "component" that then gets client side rendered? Because it's used in a context I don't know if I can move it outside of the _app.js component? Thanks so much for the help!

I have tried setting state using a useEffect hook, setting state to the value of localStorage. In a sense, I expected it to work as expected, but by the time I was accessing localStorage this way it had already been wiped clean.

Comment: Just check if `cartItems` is an empty array before setting the `localStorage` on the `useEffect`.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way, but wouldn't this cause issues as the array is also empty when the cart is empty? Using this method would prevent localStorage from ever updating. In a sense this solution solves one problem and immediately creates another, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `if (cartItems.length === 0) return` how would this cause the issue you are describing?